# How to stop an image shrinking on responsive site whilst also keeping it centred

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

This is my first post, so please be gentle. I've searched thoroughly for an answer but had no luck - I'm sure it must be something simple but I'm running out of ideas...anyway:

I'm making a responsive site but there's an image that I want to keep at a fixed size. It took me ages to work out how to do this (by removing "max-width: 100%"), however this has had the bizarre effect of changing its alignment so it is no longer centred on the page.

How can I have both? Centred and a fixed size?

Any help much appreciated.

Oh and this is what my image css is looking like at the moment:

```
img {
height: auto;
min-width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks for all your help so far - although this is still far from resolved I'm afraid. Figured I'd show my code in full as some of you have suggested, so I put it into jsfiddle. However it works absolutely fine there - the window can be resized with the image still retaining it's full dimensions and still remaining in the centre of the page. Yet with exactly the same code, when I load the 'index' page from my PC into Chrome, the image at the bottom either retains its size but drifts to the right when the window is shrunk, or it stays in the centre but shrinks to a ridiculous size. Any idea why there might be such a discrepancy?

Here's my jsfiddle anyway, which might have some clues:

http://jsfiddle.net/eggwhite/0yz6ndjh/

Thanks again.

Comment: How is your HTML set up? Could you possibly use background images and some CSS like `background-position: 50% 50%;`?

Comment: See my codepen which does that - http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK

Comment: If you don't have to have the image tag in your markup, you could also use a css background image, set the `background-position`  to `center` and the `background-size` to `100%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to add an image which should still be centered even if the parent element's width is smaller than the image. This could be done by using an image wrapper div which is pretty wide and position it accordingly. Also, the image itself should be centered in that wrapper.

In the following example, the layout has two columns, each with an image of 300x300px. If you resize the viewport (use the "Full page" view mode), the images will still be centered (see how the "x" in the placeholder images stays visible).

```css
html, body, .column {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.column {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ccf;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column + .column {
    background-color: #ffc;
    float: right;
}
.img-wrapper {
    width: 10000px;
    margin-left: calc(-5000px + 50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    Column 1
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    Column 2
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys - I tried your solution @id.ot but it didn't work. Will have a go at yours tonight Paul. Just writing this to let you know that I updated the question and added a jsfiddle thing if you get the chance to look again - only just realised you probably weren't notified before now. Thanks again!

Comment: Right, just saw this and here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/0yz6ndjh/1/ based on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by wrapping the image in a `<div>` like so:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="..." alt="random blue sky image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 250px; /* or whatever width you need the image to be */
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/8xpuorq8/) of the code.

If that didn't help, we'll ask that you present us with the problematic code. [Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) is an easy way to do that.

Comment: But what happens if the div is less than 250px wide?